# How do you find the sample sizes used in calculations on r?

Tags: r, summary, sample-size

I am running correlations between variables, some of which have missing data, so the sample size for each correlation are likely different. I tried print and summary, but neither of these shows me how big my n is for each correlation. This is a fairly simple problem that I cannot find the answer to anywhere.

Comment: are you using `cor(...,use="pairwise.complete.obs"))` ... ?

Comment: further to @BenBolker's comment you might want to see http://tinyurl.com/afcglqv

Answer (score 3):

like this..?

```
x <- c(1:100,NA)
length(x)
length(x[!is.na(x)])
```

you can also get the degrees of freedom like this...

```
y <- c(1:100,NA)
x <- c(1:100,NA)

cor.test(x,y)$parameter
```

But I think it would be best if you show the code for how your are estimating the correlation for exact help.

Comment: ..and wouldn't the sample size just be (degrees of freedom)+2 for this? :)  so the answer is.. `cor.test( x , y )$parameter + 2`

Comment: yes , estimating two parameters so `d.f.` in my case is `N-2`, I thought this solution was implicit

Comment: although for `method="spearman"` or `"kendall"` the `cor.test(x,y)$parameter` will return `NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to find the pairwise sample sizes among the columns of a matrix. If you want to apply it to (certain) numeric columns of a data frame, combine them accordingly, coerce the resulting object to matrix and apply the function.

```
# Example matrix:
xx <- rnorm(3000)
# Generate some NAs
vv <- sample(3000, 200)
xx[vv] <- NA
# reshape to a matrix
dd <- matrix(xx, ncol = 3)
# find the number of NAs per column
apply(dd, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
# tack on some column names
colnames(dd) <- paste0("x", seq(3))

# Function to find the number of pairwise complete observations 
# among all pairs of columns in a matrix. It returns a data frame
# whose first two columns comprise all column pairs

pairwiseN <- function(mat)
{
    u <- if(is.null(colnames(mat))) paste0("x", seq_len(ncol(mat))) else colnames(mat)
    h <- expand.grid(x = u, y = u)

    f <- function(x, y)
           sum(apply(mat[, c(x, y)], 1, function(z) !any(is.na(z))))
    h$n <- mapply(f, h[, 1], h[, 2])
    h
}

# Call it
pairwiseN(dd)
```

The function can easily be improved; for example, you could set `h <- expand.grid(x = u[-1], y = u[-length(u)])` to cut down on the number of calculations, you could return an n x n matrix instead of a three-column data frame, etc.

Comment: This is an awesome function! The addition of ```h <- expand.grid(x = u[-1], y = u[-length(u)]) ``` is really helpful for big datasets!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a for-loop implementation of Dennis' function above to output an n x n matrix rather than have to pivot_wide() that result. On my databricks cluster it cut the compute time for 1865 row x 69 column matrix down from 2.5 - 3 minutes to 30-40 seconds.

Thanks for your answer Dennis, this helped me with my work.

```
pairwise_nxn <- function(mat)
{
    cols <- if(is.null(colnames(mat))) paste0("x", seq_len(ncol(mat))) else colnames(mat)
    nn <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(cols), ncol = length(cols)))
    rownames(nn) <- colnames(nn) <- cols

    f <- function(x, y)
           sum(apply(mat[, c(x, y)], 1, function(z) !any(is.na(z))))
    for (i in 1:nrow(nn))
      for (j in 1:ncol(nn))
        nn[i,j] <- f(rownames(nn)[i], colnames(nn)[j])
    nn
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your variables are vectors named `a` and `b`, would something like `sum(is.na(a) | is.na(b))` help you?